# Override admin fieldset for model in app

Tags: django

[Django admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories) state that you can override templates for specific models in specific apps by putting template in `my_app/my_model` subdirectory of `templates/admin` folder in your application.

I'm trying to override `includes/fieldset.html` template for my_model in my_app. Saving it as `my_app/admin/my_app/my_model/includes/fieldset.html` doesn't seem to work, while `my_app/admin/includes/fieldset.html` does, but overrides template for all pages in admin site.

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" isn't a problem description..Please verify that you've followed each step in the link you started with (notice that it says your _project's_ `templates` directory). What is your `settings.TEMPLATE`?

Comment: I am sure that templates are set correctly - loading template from root of application template directory works. TEMPLATE include APP_DIRS: True and my_app is included in INSTALLED_APPS above django.contrib.admin

Comment: You should edit your question to fill in extra information, not hide it in the comments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the behavior is correct because not every template is getting override using this method per app or model, [please read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model).

allowed templates are :

1. app_index.html
2. change_form.html
3. change_list.html
4. delete_confirmation.html
5. object_history.html
6. popup_response.html

So what I had done is override all these per app and model or added in admin.py class `change_form_template = 'admin/appname/customtemplate.html'` this will give you full control over templates. You can / need also to change all inner templates using inner includes.